# Can't set unique email field in Simple membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm trying to get a MembershipCreateUserException to get thrown when I enter in a dup email into simplemembership. It seems like there should be something set up already because there is a MembershipCreateUserException that already exists, but I can't hit MembershipCreateUserException  with anything I've set up so far.

```
case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                return "A user name for that e-mail address already 
                exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";
```

I set a email field in Simple Membership by adding

```
public string Email { get; set; }
```

to the UserProfile class

```
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

to the RegisterModel class

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, 
model.Password, new { Email = model.Email });
```

to my Register Method in my Account Controller

Did I miss something? How do I set the email to a unique field so that the user sees a friendly error message when he tries to enter in a dup email address?

Comment: The reason it's called **Simple** MembershipProvider is because it's very simple.  It does not support that feature.  If you need it, you can either use a try/catch or implement yourself a MembershipProvider.

Comment: well it has it for duplicate usernames and has a custom exception for duplicate emails, so why wouldn't it have the ability to check that with some attribute or something??

Comment: I don't know why.  You could ask someone at Microsoft I suppose.

Comment: here is the custom exception case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                    return "A user name for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address."; How does this get called then?

Comment: It doesn't.  Take at look at the [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs) yourself.  `requiresUniqueEmail` is never used.

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no out of the box way to check for dup emails? I guess I really don't need unique emails if I already have unique usernames, but I thought I might run into a problem down the road?

Comment: That or copy the entire SimpleMembershipProvider code and make your own around line 496.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55609/discussion-between-user1186050-and-erik-philips).